# How to kill all processes with the same name?

Tags: linux, process, user, kill

I want to kill all processes with the same name that belong to a user,
for example:

```
$ps -u user_1
2345 myapp
2346 myapp
2347 myapp
2348 myapp2
2349 myapp
```

I want to kill all "myapp" processes that belong to "user_1", how can I do this?

Comment: To kill all processes, use `killall`. I'm not kidding: `man killall`.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27501/whats-the-difference-between-killall-and-pkill) to a discussion on askubuntu that might answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pkill command.

```
pkill -u user_1 myapp
```

Note that `myapp2` won't be killed as it has a different name.

Answer (score 0):

use pkill command and wild cards

`pkill -u user_name 'myap*'`

it will kill all processes starting with myap.

"?" - matches 0 or 1 character

"*" - matches 0 or more character

Comment: and @cpast is right. killall will do the same.

Comment: @Aprit I don'T believe that `killall` supports wildcards, which forces you to be very precise when passing the name of the process you would like to terminate.